# python: how to sort a list which is returned from a sql query?

Tags: python

cur is the cursor to database.

```
cur.execute(select a,b from table)
List = cur.fetchall() is like this
[('a', Decimal('1420.3345345278832575')), ('b', Decimal('380.0000000000000000')),('c', Decimal('382.0000000000000000'))]
```

I want to sort this result on basis of second item in tuple i.e decimal

I tried :

```
sorted(List,key=itemgetter(1))
```

This did not sort the list .

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on "this does not work"?

Comment: Why not just change your query to `select a, b from table order by b` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sorted` doesn't modifies the original list, it returns a new sorted version of `List`. You should assign the returned list from `sorted` to a variable:

```
>>> lis = [('a', Decimal('1420.3345345278832575')), ('b', Decimal('380.0000000000000000')),('c', Decimal('382.0000000000000000'))]
>>> new_lis = sorted(lis, key=itemgetter(1))
>>> new_lis
[('b', Decimal('380.0000000000000000')), ('c', Decimal('382.0000000000000000')), ('a', Decimal('1420.3345345278832575'))]
```

or to sort the original list use `list.sort`:

```
>>> lis = [('a', Decimal('1420.3345345278832575')), ('b', Decimal('380.0000000000000000')),('c', Decimal('382.0000000000000000'))]
>>> lis.sort(key=itemgetter(1))
>>> lis
[('b', Decimal('380.0000000000000000')), ('c', Decimal('382.0000000000000000')), ('a', Decimal('1420.3345345278832575'))]
```

Comment: @Peter Glad that helped. :) Feel free to [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) when the system allows you.